# Ajax call returned server error ORA-01403: no data found for Execute Server-Side Code

Tags: sql, oracle

I get error when I click button calculation . I want to calculate total prices wheres the product per item is on another form/table and the quantity is on the table/form and display it in column total price

```
SELECT :P9_QUANTITYS*Productsprice
INTO :P9_TOTALPRICES
FROM b_ordersdetails od
JOIN b_product pd ON od.PRODUCTSID= pd.ProductsID
WHERE pd.ProductsID= :P9_PRODUCTSID;
```

Answer (score 0):

That looks like Apex.

If query returned `NO-DATA-FOUND`, it means that there are no rows that satisfy condition(s) you applied; either

- there are no rows you can join, or - if there are - then
- `b_product` table doesn't contain row whose `productsid` column is equal to `P9_PRODUCTSID` page item value.

If you're kind of *sure* that query should return something because you tested it elsewhere (e.g. in SQL Workshop or SQL Developer), then I suspect that `P9_PRODUCTSID` isn't stored into session state and is considered to be `NULL`.

If that's the case, what to do? The simplest way is to **submit** the page: create button which - when pressed - submits and also causes all items to be put into session state so that your query works.

Another option is to use **dynamic action** - use `Set Value` to calculate that value.

On the other hand, if that's expected situation (that nothing is found and it is OK that query doesn't return anything, but you'd want to avoid error), then a simple option is to use aggregation, e.g.

```
SELECT MAX ( :P9_QUANTITYS * Productsprice)
  INTO :P9_TOTALPRICES
  FROM b_ordersdetails od JOIN b_product pd ON od.PRODUCTSID = pd.ProductsID
 WHERE pd.ProductsID = :P9_PRODUCTSID;
```

presuming that there can be only one row for each `P9_PRODUCTSID`. If there can be two or more rows, then your *original* query would return `TOO-MANY-ROWS` error (you should handle). In that case, substitute `MAX` with `SUM`, if that's OK with what you're doing.

Comment: Hi I just followed your instruction which is used dynamic action and set the value , and i set the `setting` `set type` with sql statement and run the code `SELECT :P9_QUANTITYS*Productsprice
INTO :P9_TOTALPRICES
FROM b_ordersdetails od
JOIN b_product pd ON od.PRODUCTSID= pd.ProductsID
WHERE pd.ProductsID= :P9_PRODUCTSID; `

Comment: also in `affected elements` `selection type`  I choose items `P9_TOTALPRICES` and when I run the application , I got another error whis is `Ajax call returned server error ORA-20987: APEX - Unable to bind "P9_TOTALPRICES". Use double quotes for multi byte items or verify length of item is 30 bytes or less. Use v() syntax to reference items longer than 30 bytes` . Can you help me how to solve this. :'(

Comment: Remove INTO clause from dynamic action's query; you set it in "affected elements".

Comment: It not working , the sql statement does not return any value

Comment: No idea, then; I've said everything I meant to say. If possible, create working example on apex.oracle.com, share developer's credentials so that we could have a look and - hopefully - assist.

Comment: Yes , I can do that if you dont mind , you can give me your username

Comment: It's up to you, create developer with any username you want.